# Graphs in PHP errors

Tags: php, mysql, graph

I am trying to fetch from the database data and to generate a graph. I am using phpgraphlib, http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/tutorial-mysql-and-phpgraphlib. I downloaded the libgd from https://github.com/libgd/libgd/releases
and also the phpgraphlib. I have PHP 5.5 and the `php_gd2.dll` extension I think it is enabled by default in the `php.ini` file.

I get 2 errors:

> Warning: require_once(phpgraphlib.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\graph.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'phpgraphlib.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\graph.php on
>   line 3

I also undertsand that something goes wrong the path and the directories. Any help? Thanks in advance!!!

```
    <?php

      require_once("phpgraphlib.php");
      $graph=new PHPGraphLib(400,300);

     //connection to MySQL database

    $link =mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Could not connect :'. mysql_error());

    //select db
    mysql_selected_db('mynewdb') or die('Could not select database');

   $dataArray=array();

   //get data from database
    $sql="SELECT year1,year2 * FROM scores WHERE crit='interesting semester' AND sid='13'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

   if ($result) {
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $crit=$row["crit"];
            $year1=$row["year1"];
            $year2=$row["year2"];
           //add to data array
            $dataArray[$crit]=$count;
         }
   }

       //configure graph
         $graph->addData($dataArray);
         $graph->setTitle("Interesting Semester");
         $graph->setGradient("lime", "green");
         $graph->setBarOutlineColor("black");
         $graph->createGraph();

   ?>
```

Comment: The errors say that php can't find the package you downloaded. It looks like you have not installed your phpgraphlib package into your php in the way php expects. Please review the way you installed it, and provide more information about that.

Answer (score 0):

please place your file phpgraphlib.php in ./  or C:\XAMPP\php\PEAR